# Why does .NET currency format include a currency symbol?

Tags: .net, localization, currency

This code: `Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu-HU"), "{0:C}", 1234.56M))` will produce the following output: 1 234,56 Ft, which is technically correct, but how does it come to guess the currency??

This behaviour means that simply changing display culture from hu-HU to en-US will multiply the value with more than 200, depending on the current rates. You would never make the mistake of billing 500 HUF insted of 500 USD. Obvious.

The only "nice" way of setting the currency is cloning the desired culture and setting the currency symbol:

```
var format = NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).Clone() as NumberFormatInfo;
format.CurrencySymbol = "asd";
Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format(format, "{0:C}", 1234.56M));
```

This works correct producing `asd1,234.56`, but so much cumbersome.

My questions are:

1. What is the ratio behind defaulting to a national currency in this global world we have been living in for decades?
2. How come there is no way of specifying the amount and the currency in a more related manner since they are so much coupled?
3. Bonus: if I use sk-SK for culture, I get euros for "default" currency. If I change to Framework 2.0 I should get `Sk` (for Slovak koruna) since in 2005 it was the national currency. (Well, it does not happen. But I haven't tried it on any system that has no later than 2.0.)

UPDATE:
Conclusions:

1. Defaulting currency from culture is all normal for some, strange for others (including me)
2. There is no 'money amount' type as there are no types for length, weight, and so on, where is the limit? Virtlink created a library for this: [M42 Financial](https://bitbucket.org/Virtlink/m42-financial/)

Comment: It displays it because you asked for it.  Just use another format specifier if you don't want it.  Like "N2".

Comment: You are confusing formatting with data.  If you bill at the wrong exchange rate or wrong currency that is not a formatting issue.

Comment: Although this is one of the "not constructive" questions according to the rules of stackoverflow, this is a very interesting question.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190906/currency-formatting-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed my mind: I agree with you that it is strange that the currency is part of the culture.

It is *not common* in .NET and Java to specify the unit with a value. You generally don't specify a temperature, a distance or a currency with a unit. For most intents and purposes the unit is assumed by the developer: meters for distance and Celsius for temperature. There is no default unit of distance or unit of temperature specified in .NET for a given culture.

To be consistent, the .NET Framework should also not have added currency information to a culture. Most people deal with more than one currency, and some countries even accept multiple currencies. Not everyone of a given culture will use one and only one currency.

The .NET framework contains a `System.Currency` class but it is hidden (internal), and only used for the `Decimal.ToOACurrency()` method. It isn't really useful either. Java contains a `Currency` class since 2002, but as the .NET Framework was created in 2000 and many design mistakes were copied from Java, this may be one of them. However, I couldn't find information on whether the Java `Locale` class contains (or contained) any currency information, and I'm not psychic.

Well, continuing from the idea that units are never specified in .NET and there should not have been a default currency for a culture, then where should they have put the currency unit of a monetary value? They should have created a `Currency` class, of course.

Comment: ...  which are all valid points for number formatting. But how can the currency be guessed?

Comment: Your examples vary both in format AND content. Ten thousand euros is very much different from ten thousand dollars, whichever culture they are displayed in. I'm missing the clear distinction between formatting and content. Currency is content, not format. (Location of the currency sign IS format, though.)

Comment: @StefanSteinegger The currency symbol is in the culture info class for the specified culture.

Comment: Your struct is the natural way, it should be a system type IMO. And also, the currency field should be a decicated Currency type with all information like symbol, 3-letter code, sort name, long name, whatever.

Comment: Accepted to respect your work. I guess, there will be no actual answer   :)

Comment: "It is not common in .NET and Java to specify the unit with a value. You generally don't specify a temperature, a distance or a currency with a unit." <-- And this is a constant source of horrible, expensive bugs (e.g. https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/bug-day-ariane-5-disaster ); to avoid bugs like that in my projects I use a `struct Money` which pairs a `Decimal` value with a 3-letter ISO currency code. (This is a practical example of [a refinement-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_type)).

Answer (score 2):

I just think that this is not meant to be used when multiple currencies may appear in the application. It might be useful when you have a simple application which handles money just as numbers which have to be interpreted in local currency.

In all other cases, don't use it.

I don't think that there are many such applications where it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what the designers were thinking, but their decisions make good sense to me. To answer your questions:

1. Most of us and our clients deal with a single currency, which is dependent on the country in which we're living. It makes sense to default to the default currency for that culture.
2. The currency symbol and number format are set individually because it's very likely that when changing currency symbols you want to keep the default number format. For example if I (in the U.S.) were printing an amount in British Pounds, I wouldn't want the number format to change--just the currency symbol. If I had to set them both, I would have to know not only the new currency symbol, but also the specific number format I'm using. Also, if they were combined then changing the number format (for non-currency values) would also require me to specify the currency symbol. Unless you had two totally separate number formats ... which would just be crazy.
3. No answer on that particular problem.

In short, having two separate settings gives you more flexibility and keeps things simple. Combining things would make more work to change things individually.

Comment: With the built-in currency handing, there isn't a nice way for an en-US application to display British Pounds. I either need to show them in the US format with a $ sign, use the clone() technique from the question, or implement my own money formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Why does .NET currency format include a currency symbol?

Because it is a currency format.

Comment: So you mean it does not matter if five pounds or five euros, it's just a presentation issue.

Comment: Really you expect individually currencies to be a datatypes such the you cannot add euros to dollars.  What about pound and kg?   What about 1/1/2008 and 2008-1-1 - are those the same date?   Where does is stop - should SQL have datatypes for euros and dollars?

Comment: You are right with this. As @Virtlink pointed out above, dimensions or unites are rarely encapsulated with amounts.

Comment: OK en-US and en-GB.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=VS.71).aspx  What cultures on that list produce the wrong currency symbol?  If so then you could report it to MSFT as a bug.

Comment: Just check my 'bonus' question: what does .NET Framework 2.0 has for sk-SK? In 2005, it obviously was the national currency. A program written for .NET2.0 might behave strange now when Slovakia has euros.

Comment: @Dercsár And timezones have some strange behaviors. SO is for specific programming questions.  SO cannot answer for why MSFT software has a behavior - only how to deal with it.  As for sk-SK - the way I would deal with it is not use .NET 2.0.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know .NET but does your formatter allow you to leave off the "M" in the format string?

So this: `1234.56` instead of this `1234.56M`

Comment: The literal type has no effect on the formatting. I've tried it with different types (M,D, even L).

Comment: `M` is just to declare a decimal constant, instead of a double. I don't think that decimals are formatted differently.

Comment: Gotcha. It was just a thought.

Comment: Including the M is really important, otherwise you'll switch from the absolute-precision decimal type to the variable-precision double type. A variable precision type is only ever an approximation, so you may find pennies/cents being added or removed from your values for no obvious reason.